# sendmail dead but subsys locked

Tags: sendmail, linux-server, oracle-linux

An Oracle 6.8 server cannot send mail. The service status is like this:

```
 [root@myserver]# service sendmail status
    sendmail dead but subsys locked
    sm-client (pid  349376) is running...
```

I removed */var/lock/subsys/sendmail*, i killed the sendmail process and then i restarted the sendmail service. The new error code is like this:

```
[root@myserver subsys]# rm /var/lock/subsys/sendmail
  rm: remove regular empty file `/var/lock/subsys/sendmail'? yes
[root@myserver subsys]# kill -9 $(pidof sendmail)
[root@myserver subsys]# service sendmail start
  Starting sendmail:                                         [  OK  ]
[root@myserver subsys]# service sendmail status
  sendmail dead but subsys locked
  sm-client dead but pid file exists
```

Some people resolved this problem with stop postfix but this server does not have postfix.

How can I restart this service without restart the server?

Comment: I restarted the sendmail service and the new status of sendmail like this:

    sendmail dead but subsys locked
    sm-client (pid  217058) is running...

Comment: any luck it, i'm having same problem?